# Appwrite: user permissions with posts

Tags: appwrite

I'm new to using Appwrite, and I can't find a way to add a permission for a user to see only their posts. How add new attribute to posts document as user_id

Answer (score 0):

When you create a document in an Appwrite Collection, you can add document-level permissions as well, so that only a user can read their documents.

This would require two steps:

- **In the Appwrite Console**

For your database collection, set the collection permissions as shown in the image
[image: Collection settings]

As seen in the image, all users are given `create`, `update`, and `delete` permissions but not `read`. You must also enable `Document Security`

- **When creating a document**

In your codebase, when you create a document, you must add the permissions using the SDK directly. Here is an [example of the same from one of my personal projects](https://github.com/adityaoberai/BackgroundRemover/blob/f86240a0a2cea084bfefcd3d8c7bda704c3175b2/src/lib/db.js#L19) in JavaScript (Web SDK)

```js
async function addImage(userId, imageId) {
  return await databases.createDocument(databaseId, 
    collectionId,
    ID.unique(),
    {
      userId: userId,
      imageId: imageId
    },
    [Permission.write(Role.user(userId)), Permission.read(Role.user(userId))]
  );
}
```

Learn more about Appwrite Permissions in our [docs](https://appwrite.io/docs/products/databases/permissions#document-level)